# Initialize all UIViewControllers in UITabBarController without showing them, using Storyboard - objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I'm using `Storyboard` first time, and I've created `UITabBarController` application. I've got 4 `UINavigationControllers` in `UITabBarController`. At the start only first `UINavigationController` with root `UIViewController` initializes, but other 3 initizlize only when I select them. How to init them all? I need instance each of them at the start.

For example I need to set data from first `UIViewController` to the fourth, but to do that now, I need to select it first. I've put breakpoints in each `UIViewContoller` in the `viewDidLoad` method, and breakpoint enables only when I select this `UIViewController`.

Is there way to init them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im am pretty sure that the `UINavigationControllers` together with their root `UIViewController` are instantiated as soon as you load the `UITabBarController` from the storyboard. Therefore you should be able to send messages to them.

But the `view` of a `UIViewController` is loaded only when needed, therefore the `viewDidLoad` method is only hit when you select that tab.

The `view` of a view controller can also be unloaded at runtime, when the view is not visible and memory is low.

Comment: I see, but is there way to initialize view without selecting UIViewController?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need to do that because I initialize NSMutableArrays in viewDidLoad method. And I put data from first UIViewController to this NSMutableArray.

Comment: You should store the data from the first view controller in a property of the fourth view controller. The `viewDidLoad` method can then use the data in that property. - The view itself is loaded by `loadView` and the documentation states explicitly that you should never call this method directly. Also the view maybe unloaded and reloaded later.